# What is the equivalent of log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator in Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: c#-4.0, enterprise-library, log4net-configuration, enterprise-library-5

I am using VS2010 and want to find the equivalent of `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator` in MS Enterprise Library 5.0. Just like it is possible to embed the location of logging configuration file in `AssemblyInfo.cs` for log4net, by

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"C:\Test\Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I want to be able to specify the config file for Enterprise Library as well. 
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analogous attribute in Enterprise Library 5.  One approach would be to use FileConfigurationSource to programmatically load the config file you want and then configure Enterprise Libary.  For example:

```
FileConfigurationSource fcs = 
    new FileConfigurationSource(
        @"C:\Test\entlib.config"
    );

var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(fcs);

EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = 
    EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(fcs);
```

If you wanted to you could create your own Enterprise Library XmlConfigurator which wraps the above code.  However note that if multiple assemblies are all configuring Enterprise Library with different configuration files they will overwrite each others config.